# Is there a word for someone who loves meeting new people?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that is more specific than "friendly" or "amicable". Thank you for your help!

Comment: Extrovert would be used when describing the person, i.e. "Paul is an extrovert".

Outgoing or Sociable would be used when describing the action, i.e. "Paul is very sociable".

Answer (score 1):

"Gregarious" may be the word you're looking for; calling someone "gregarious" usually implies that they *are* friendly or amiable, but also that they particularly enjoy socializing.

Answer (score 1):

**Gregarious**

A person fond of company; sociable

[Webster's]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Extrovert**.

Extrovert - A sociable and outgoing person.

Comment: *Sociable* is even better.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [***outgoing***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/outgoing) which means:

> Friendly and socially confident: *she’s always been very outgoing and
>   she’s got heaps of friends*

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

The word is broadly used to describe people who are sociable, friendly and amicable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***mixer***

> A sociable person: *She's outgoing and a good mixer* [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mixer)